# Laravel Passport authorization for only 1 third party web

Tags: laravel

I want to know how can i create a Access Client for a especific website. 
I’m trying to create a postback url where a postback route will receive data from a third part website.

The 3rd party website do a Post to my website postback route and send url parameters. (Like id, ip, etc)

I know that I can create a passport client and then use client access tokens. But I don’t understand how can I make that this token and this client only works with this 3rd party website and i don’t want that if I take a user token generated with email and password to the same postback could send data to this.

I was researching but i can’t understand how it works.

Comment: When you create the user token, you need to send also the client id an client secret. So the user token is generated for a specific client.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how can i middleware that postback route only for this client?

Comment: I'm confused... but you use a token. So only this client will be authorized.

Comment: Ok so your are telling me that I have to generate the token with this client and then use it with the postback url. But middleware for clients accept any client. Or am I wrong. What happen if I create other client and other token. This route is with client middleware. Sorry for my confusion. I don’t really get it

Comment: You can make a test :D